# One-line assignment: If (condition) variable = value1 else value2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I do something like this?

```
if params[:property] == nil 
 @item.property = true
else 
 @item.property = false
```

Always forget the proper syntax to write it in one line.

In PHP it would be like this:

```
@item.property=(params[:property]==nil)true:false
```

Is it the same in rails?

Comment: That's not valid PHP code, is it? That statement looks like this afaik:  $item->property = ($something === NULL) ? true : false

Comment: maybe, that's just an example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the ternary operator:

```
@item.property = params[:property] ? true : false
```

or force a boolean conversion ("not not" operation)  :

```
@item.property = !!params[:property]
```

note : in ruby, it is a common idiom *not* to use true booleans, as any object other than `false` or `nil` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

m_x answer is perfect but you may be interested to know other ways to do it, which may look better in other circumstances:

```
if params[:property] == nil then @item.property = true else @item.property = false end
```

or

```
@item.property = if params[:property] == nil then true else false end
```